# InnoDB and tmp_table issue

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a set of three InnoDB tables in a MySQL server on which I do a simple SELECT.

```
SELECT s.type, s.Price,l.ratio, o.type, 
FROM Structures s, Orders o, Legs l 

WHERE s.type in ('type1','type2',...)  
AND o.ID >= s.ID* 10  
AND o.ID<= s.ID * 10 + s.orderNumber -1  
AND l.ID >= s.ID * 10  
AND l.ID <= s.ID * 10 + s.legNumber -1  

ORDER BY s.type, s.FurthestExpiration, s.NearestExpiration
```

After a certain number of rows added (around 1,800 for Structures, 3,000 for Legs and Orders), I cannot execute this request and I see in MySQL workbench that the request's state is

```
Copying to the tmp table.
```

The request never finishes.

Some remarks:

1. If I do the same request in the Workbench, it succeeds.
2. If I remove the ORDER BY clause, it succeeds.
3. If I switch the engine from InnoDB to MyISAM, it works.

I don't really care about using InnoDB or MyISAM, but I am not sure that's an incompatibility with InnoDB, I suspect there are some issues in my DB parameters/design.

Thanks for any clue!

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do: `s.type in ('',...,'')` .. Is this just test-data omitted, or do you really have this in your code? What are you trying to say there?

Comment: It should be clearer now, sorry for that.

Comment: InnoDB has its own query/key caches, seperate from the rest of the DB engines in MySQL. If switching to MyISAM lets the query work, then most likely your InnoDB's cache settings are too low, forcing mysql to use disk instead of memory buffers.

Comment: Do "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%'" and give us the output. It's probably that you have misconfigured InnoDB settings.

Comment: I cannot post everything in comment and cannot answer my question before 8 hours.

    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size, 1048576
    innodb_autoextend_increment, 8
    innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb, 0
    innodb_buffer_pool_size, 8388608

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree that this is a "simple select". What do you want to do here? Because if I see this correctly, this will be a HUGE (implicit) join. You are joining by saying this: `FROM Structures s, Orders o, Legs l`, but there is no `s.id = o.id` kind-of thing, only a comparison. How big will your resultset be? There might not be an easy index either, but you'll have to check `EXPLAIN` for that.

Anyway, I see no reason it should never finish, although because of the query itself not being very efficient it might be a long time before this  `Copying to the tmp table.` state finishes. (obviously depending on the fact *if* the query is inefficient :)  )
Maybe you are hitting a limit of some sort (caching, memory etc) on that amount of rows, and so it starts to become really slow, and it looks like it's not finishing.

My advice would be to make some explicit joins ( `table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`) if possible, or at least check how 'heavy' the query is.

Comment: I am getting around 100 rows for the structures table in average.
I have migrated from MS SQL recently, where I had 500,000+ rows for each table and I never encountered any issue.